# IONICとSAILS.JS連携について

Tags: iphone, mongodb, sails.js

こんにちは。USBコードをIPONEにつないでローカル環境(MAC)でsailsを立ち上げ、IPONEにてIONICアプリを立ち上げ、画面項目を入力しsubmitすると以下のエラーが出てしまいます。
デバッグでAuthenticationServiceのloginUserメソッドが呼ばれて$http.postメソッドが呼ばれているところまで確認しています。サーバーサイドのほうにはpostが届いておりません。どなたかお知恵をお貸しいただければと思いこちらに質問させていただきました。どうぞ宜しくお願いします。

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (login, line 0) http://localhost:1337/user/login
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (register-device-token, line 0) https://push.ionic.io/api/v1/register-device-token
```

ionic側のソースは以下になります。

```
factory('AuthenticationService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', function($http, $q, localStorageService){

  function loginUser(post){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post('http://localhost:1337/user/login', post)
    .success(function (data) {
      if (data.error || !data.user) {
        deferred.reject(data.error);
      }

      localStorageService.set('user', data.user);
      user = data.user;

      deferred.resolve(data.user);
    })
    .error(function () {
      deferred.reject('error');
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    login: loginUser
  };
}])
```

コントローラで上のサービスを読んでます。
パラメータのuserに画面の入力情報を入れています。

```
  // コントローラの中
  AuthenticationService.login(user).then(function (result){
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $state.go('app.profile');
  }, function (error) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    console.log('error', error);
  });
```

以下サーバーサイドのコード　↓
サーバーサイドのルータ(sails.js)

```
module.exports.routes = {
  ......

  'POST /user/login': {
    controller: 'LoginController',
    action: 'create',
    cors: true
  },

  ......
}
```

LoginControllerです。

```
create: function(req, res) {
  'use strict';
  sails.log.debug('create user method in');

  var user = req.params,
      uuid = NodeUuid.v4();

  sails.log.debug('user = ' + JSON.stringify(user));
  // Validator.validateUserInfo(user);
  User.create({
    //画面からの入力情報
  }).exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      if (err.code == 11000) {
        StatusService.returnResponse(res, Constants.statusCode.BadRequest, err, Constants.message.error.alreadyExistsEmail);
      }
    } else {
      StatusService.returnResponse(res, Constants.statusCode.OK, null, '');
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: 自己解決しました。　localhost:1337 → ローカルのIPアドレス:1337で通りました。